# Error: Value of type string has no member componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, swift3

The following code throws the following error: "Value of type string has no member componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet"

This code is from another project that worked before in swift versions 1 or 2 but no longer works.

```
   import Foundation

extension String {

    func split() -> [String] {
        return self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
            CharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
            .filter({$0 != ""});
    }
}

extension Array {

    func unique<T: Equatable>() -> [T] {
        var uniqueValues = [T]();

        for value in self {
            if !contains(uniqueValues, value as T) {
                uniqueValues.append(value as! T);
            }
        }
        return uniqueValues;
    }

    func first<T>(test:(T) -> Bool) -> T? {
        for value in self {
            if test(value as! T) {
                return value as? T;
            }
        }
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Swift 2 or Swift 3? You tagged both...

Comment: @AMomchilov I would like to use swift 3 however this code is coming from swift 2 I believe where I removed the 'NS' syntactic sugar.

Comment: You can use trailing closure notation for `.filter` btw

Comment: By the way, your `first(test:_)` method is just duplicating the functionality of the built-in  `first(where:)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for [`components(separatedBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1690726-components):

```
func split() -> [String] {
    return self.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).filter{!$0.isEmpty}
}
```

Comment: Swift 3 there is no `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()`. The correct would be `return components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).filter{!$0.isEmpty}`