# Swift 3 conversion error in phone number validation

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Below is the code in Swift2 which i am using in an extension but while migrating to swift 3 it shows the following errors. Any idea how to sort this out?

```
var isPhoneNumber: Bool {

    let charcter  = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "+0123456789").inverted
    var filtered:NSString!
    let inputString:NSArray = self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charcter)
    filtered = inputString.componentsJoined(by: "") as NSString!
    return  self == filtered

}
```

The errors shown are:

1. **Value of type 'String' has no member 'componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet'**
2. **Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'NSString!'**

Comment: 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210048/error-value-of-type-string-has-no-member-componentsseparatedbycharactersinset
2: What is the type of `self`?

Comment: 2: self & filtered should have same type 'String' or 'NSString!'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was on the same page:

```
let charcter  = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+0123456789").inverted
let inputString = self.components(separatedBy: charcter).joined(separator: "")
return  self == inputString
```